# WebStorm's TypeScript Lint: Callback Parameter Type

Tags: typescript, callback, webstorm, lint

Hope someone could help me, I'm having a slight problem trying to figure out how to get WebStorm's TypeScript Lint to handle specific callback data, that isn't optional.

I have a function that I am exporting:

```
test(callback: (data: string) => void) {
    callback('Hello from Index');
}
```

And using it:

```
TestClass.test(() => {
      console.log(`This is data from Tester: ${}`); 
})
```

But the TypeScript checker is not picking up on that I am not typing in the argument that is not optional. The callback parameter was specifically set in the function;

`callback: (data: string)`

My main objective here is to force every function that doesn't have optional arguments to at the very least type the arguments (Not necessarily using the exact name in the exported function, but having it as a must, as such:

```
TestClass.test((result) => {
      console.log(This is data from Tester: ${}); 
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is by design. If you have a callback parameter that will receive parameters, but the implementation of the callback does not use the parameters there is no issue, the parameters are just ignored.

Comment: Is there any way to force that the implementation of the callback at the very least is set, not necessarily used, of course, such as any settings in the typescript.json? I am completely new to typescript, and even though there's good documentation, it's hard to find the correct terms to google, to get proper results.

Comment: Sure we can, actually forcing usage is simpler, we can just use `"noUnusedParameters": true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If you have a callback parameter that will receive parameters, but the implementation of the callback does not use the parameters there is no issue, the parameters are just ignored.

We can do some 'clever' conditional typing to force the compiler to give an error if there is no parameter specified:

```
type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;
type HasArgument<T, TError> =  (T extends (arg: infer U)=> void ? IsValidArg<U> extends true ? {} : TError :TError )

class TestClass {
    static test<T extends (data: string) => void>(callback: T & HasArgument<T, "You need to have an argument to the implementation">): void
    static test(callback: (data: string) => void) {
        callback('Hello from Index');
    }
}

//OK
TestClass.test((data) => {
    console.log(`This is data from Tester: ${data}`);
})
//Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '"You need to have an argument to the implementation"'.
TestClass.test(() => {
    console.log(`This is data from Tester: ${0}`);
})
```

The error message is not ideal but is explicit enough.

You can also force the caller to do something with the parameter using `"noUnusedParameters": true` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Thank you, the noUnusedParamters was exactly what I was looking for!